# Why does one site use different font sizes in the mobile site?

Tags: support, design, mobile-web

I keep tabs for several sites open on my phone (Android 7.1.1) in Chrome (v 63.0.3239.111).  On all of them except one, the font size used for question titles on the main page looks consistent.  Then there's Beer, Wine, & Spirits, where things are a little smaller.  No, it's not just blurry vision from imbibing.

To eliminate variables for this question, I'll compare this site specifically to another beta site.  Even if there is any per-site styling in the mobile theme, all beta sites use the same style.  Here they are, side by side:

[image: two mobile sites]

It's not a large difference, but you can see that both the text size and the line spacing in the titles are smaller in the screen shot on the left.

Browser text scaling is set to 110%.  That's a browser-wide setting.  I have no site-specific or tab-specific modifications on either site.  This difference has existed for months; it's not a consequence of the recent, now-reverted changes to the mobile site.

Why the difference?  It's not a big deal (or a big difference), but I can't figure out why one site should be different from another when they all use the same theme and the same browser.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] for me.

Comment: That's something on your side. Titles in mobile theme have fixed font size of 14px, set in the CSS, cross network. If your browser refuse to honor that, it's the browser's fault.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289166/chrome-on-android-resizes-font (possible explanation of the behavior.)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard something is causing certain sites -- consistently, not just based on current content -- to render with larger fonts and others to render with smaller ones.  (Today I discovered a second case, a private beta that is small like Beer, Wine, & Spirits.)  It's of course possible that my browser is doing something wacky, but since it happens with SE sites (pretty much the only thing I use that browser for) I thought I might find help here.

Comment: Well, maybe something you installed on your phone... can you try on other mobile device?